# Passing any enum of a given type as function parameter

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller

I'm working on a project for an AVR microcontroller using the Arduino framework.

I'm building a simple error tracking system structured as a class (`ErrorManager`). I have defined a couple of functions like

```cpp
void ErrorManager::error(??? errorCode) { // more on ??? later
    // rise error in some way
}
```

I want to define error codes separately in different modules that make up this project. In each module, I would like to define an `enum class` containing the codes for that module, and then pass them to the `error` function above:

```cpp
namespace someNamespace /* or class SomeClass */ {

// cointains error codes for this class/module/part of the code
enum class ErrorCodes : unsigned int { 
    none = 0,
    anError,
    someOtherError
}

void foo() {
    error(ErrorCodes::anError);
}

}
```

(let `errManager` be the `ErrorManager` object declared in one module of my project)

I could accomplish this by writing `unsigned int` in `???` and using an `enum` instead of an `enum class`, but that would mean that the error code names would be in scope in the whole module namespace or, at least, in the whole class where they are defined, and I would rather avoid this.

Is there a way to do this with an `enum class`? For example, something to write in `???` which means "Take any Enum (with unsigned int, or some a `typedef`ined type, or even any integer type) as parameter"?

Comment: why not `void ErrorManager::error(ErrorCodes errorCode)`?

Comment: @Juraj Because `ErrorCodes` is not known when `error` is defined, sorry that I didn't made that clear. I'm updating the question.

Comment: then use a namespace instead of enum. or an anonymous enum wrapped in a namespace

Comment: thanks, I didn't think of the latter possibility!! But, out of interest, is it possible in any way to define a function which takes any `enum class` as parameter? Like some kind of inheritance mechanism for `enum`s? (I believe true inheritance doesn't exist, is that correct?)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a template:

```
template <typename T>   
void /*ErrorManager::*/error(T x) 
{ 
    unsigned int errorcode = (unsigned int)x;
    // Do something with it
} 

enum class ErrorCodes : unsigned int {
    none = 0,
    anError,
    someOtherError
};

void foo() {
    error<ErrorCodes>(ErrorCodes::anError);
}
```

It should be possible to restrict the template to be an enum using [`enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`is_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum), but I can't get it compiled at the moment. It seems there are standard libraries missing for Arduino.

Please note that the default underlying type of an `enum` is `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still have a question: if I use a template, how can I make sure that I'll never call `error` with something that can not be converted to `unsigned int`?

Comment: With a template class you will get distinct realizations with each error code class. That adds up on code size. However, this might not be a problem.

Comment: If `T` cannot be converted to `unsigned int` I would expect a compiler diagnostic message.